# Is it possible to display a property of my customer QT widget in Chinese

Tags: qt, custom-widgets, qproperty

I want to display a [property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/properties.html) of my customer QT widget in Chinese. Is it possible?

I've tried give a Chinese text to Q_PROPERTY macro as second parameter, but it leads to compile error.

```
Q_PROPERTY(type name
       READ getFunction
       [WRITE setFunction]
       [RESET resetFunction]
       [NOTIFY notifySignal]
       [REVISION int]
       [DESIGNABLE bool]
       [SCRIPTABLE bool]
       [STORED bool]
       [USER bool]
       [CONSTANT]
       [FINAL])
```

Comment: Please edit your post to add the exact code you used. Also have a look at the editor help, the code syntax you used is not supported here. Just indent code lines with four spaces.

Comment: @Kub Ober, thanks very much for your edit.